# Windows 8.1 won't accept my Media Center Pack Product Key

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-center, windows-8.1, product-key, windows-8.1-upgrade

I just installed Windows 8.1 Pro as an upgrade from an ISO torrent. I was able to activate my original Windows 8 key successfully. However, I tried to activate my Media Center Pack key that I purchased for Windows 8 and it errors out the first try. When I try to activate it again, it then says "This key won't work. Check it and try again, or try a different key.". Do I have to purchase the key again?

Thanks

Comment: Did you use a Generic license to do the upgrade.  You really should have use the `Windows Store` in order apply the update.  There is a solution but it requires your original `Windows 8 Professional` license key.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I used a generic license. I have my original Windows 8 Professional key.

Comment: I posted and answer with the information you seek with RTM in the title.  After you activate your Professional key again you have to upgrade to MC again